# Small dencryption program logic advice

Tags: java

This is my first ever post to Stack overflow! Anyways, I was looking for some help on my logic with this small program I was assigned. I made an encryption filter in Java, and now I have to make a program that decrypts it.

Here is the logic behind my encryption (that works):

```
char[] I = new char[a.length()];
for(int u = 0 ; u < a.length() ; ++u) {
   I[u] = a.charAt(u); 
}

int[] ASCII = new int[I.length];
int[] castASCII = new int[I.length];
char[] EncryptedI = new char[I.length];
for(int x = 0; x < I.length; ++x) {
    ASCII[x] = I[x];
    castASCII[x] = (int) I[x];
    EncryptedI[x] = (char) (ASCII[x] + (2 + x));
    System.out.print(castASCII[x] + " ");
    System.out.println(EncryptedI[x]);
}
try {
    FileWriter FileE = new FileWriter("PassEncrypt.txt");
    PrintWriter eFile = new PrintWriter(FileE);
    eFile.println(EncryptedI);
    eFile.close();
} catch(IOException e) {
    e.getMessage();
}
```

}

For the decryption I basically tried to do the same thing but backwards.

```
for(int x = I.length - 1; x >= 0; --x) {
    ASCII[x] = I[x];
    castASCII[x] = (int) I[x];
    DecryptedI[x] = (char) (ASCII[x] - (2 - x));
}
```

So someone much smarter than me can probably tell this doesn't really work, but I don't understand why. In my head if I just applied the opposite change it should come up with the same string that was encrypted. But it comes up with something quite different.

Comment: At a first glance, you're not making an opposite change . You're adding `2 + x` when "encrypting", but you're not subtracting `2 + x` when "decrypting".  Instead, you're subtracting `2 - x`, which is going to be a different number.

Comment: This was it, thank you so much! it works like a charm! I'm trying to mark your answer as the right one. but cant find the button

Comment: @Jordan You should post this as an answer so that the OP can accept it.

Comment: You are probably aware of this, but just in case: This is a **toy example** of encryption, not a secure crypto-algorithm. **Do not attempt protecting your secrets with it.**

Comment: @IgorF. yes thank you for the warning, but im new to java and this is an assignment for class,  I never intended to use this as real security, i figured real encryption is much more complicated and protective.

Comment: You should also be aware that you are not (necessarily) working with ASCII. Java strings contain UTF-16 code units, and only values that are strictly less than 128 are the same as ASCII values. Particularly, when you add 2 + x to a value, you could easily get a Unicode code point that is not ASCII. This probably doesn't matter to you, but it is good to be clear on these concepts.